# How can I send an email after completing an action? - swiftui firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So in the app the user have the ability to continue using the app as a guest
that means that the user won't have an account

the user can book a tour through the app and the app asks for some information including his email

so I was wondering is there any way to send an email to the user confirming his booking? even though the user doesn't have an account?

I tried doing something like when the user gets send a verification email but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has no built-in API to send arbitrary emails for application specific use-cases.

If you need something like that, you will need to build it yourself on existing primitives. For an example of this, see the Cloud Functions sample on [Sending Confirmation Emails with Cloud Functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/email-confirmation)
.